# Audio is no longer working, after trying to fix In-game sound for playonlinux

Tags: sound, wine, pulseaudio, alsa, playonlinux

```
So, following this guide here (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) this is the output for the ALSA debug script:
```

http://pastebin.com/zZTAxeQN

Everything was working perfectly, then after a reboot to fix a glitch in a game ran with Wine, no sound.

Comment: Heres further diagnostic... Would really appreciate some help =[  http://pastebin.com/iT72qLM1

Answer (score 0):

can you try to remove the latest 3.13.0-46 kernel and install the 3.13.0-45 kernel with the following command:

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-46 linux-headers-3.13.0-46-generic`

And install with:

`sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.13.0-45-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-45 linux-headers-3.13.0-45-generic`

Finally, reboot you computer to see if it works.